# AWS Rekognition : indexFaces throw regular expression pattern error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am researching on AWS rekognition and end up in very common problem

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'mainbucket/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx/family' at 'image.s3Object.bucket' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [0-9A-Za-z\\.\\-_]*"
```

Code [ copy paste from documentation - except configure to run with my AWS configs]

```
var params = {
    CollectionId: "collectionidnewbatch", 
    DetectionAttributes: [
    ], 
    ExternalImageId: "testphotoid", 
    Image: {
     S3Object: {
      Bucket: "mainbucket/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx/family",
      Name: "ab1.jpg"
     }
    }
   };
   rekognition.indexFaces(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data); 
   });
```

I tried giving nested bucket path in Source but It do not recognize the Source key ! and I'm not sure how can I give nested path in this request.

any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bucket names do not contain slashes.

If an object is in a sub-directory, then include the full path in the `Name`:

```
    Image: {
     S3Object: {
      Bucket: "mainbucket",
      Name: "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx/family/ab1.jpg"
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please share me the documentation where I can find this knowledge

Comment: [Object Key and Metadata - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)